# Can't divide by function for use in ordinary differential equations

Tags: numpy, math, scipy, physics, ode

I'm a first year maths and physics student and have next to no experience in python and this is my first time working with SciPy.
This is why I ran into some trouble when trying to handle ODEs;
My Problem is that I'm not able to divide by a previously defined function for use in another ODE.

I tried replacing dvdt with the code from the return statement in the previously defined function dvdt but that doesn't work since v is not defined inside dxdt.
Casting dvdt to float also doesn't work, since I can't cast to a function.

I'm absolutely clueless about what to do, so I turned to StackOverflow in hopes of getting some suggestions :O).

This is my code:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def dvdt(t, v):
    
    k = 0.3
    Fs = 200000
    m0 = 10000
    lam = 200
    
    return (Fs + k*v**2) / (m0 - lam*t)

v0 = 0

def dxdt(t, x):
    
    k = 0.3
    Fs = 200000
    m0 = 10000
    lam = 200
    
    # This is where the Problem arises.

    return math.sqrt(Fs / (dvdt*k))

# Inserting ((Fs + k*v**2) / (m0 - lam*t)) for dvdt didn't help either, since v is not defined inside dxdt :/

x0 = 0

t = np.linspace(0, 30, 100)

sol_v = integrate.solve_ivp(dvdt, t_span = (0, max(t)), y0=[v0], t_eval=t)
v_sol = sol_v.y[0]

sol_x = integrate.solve_ivp(dxdt, t_span = (0, max(t)), y0=[x0], t_eval=t)
x_sol = sol_x.y[0]

plt.plot(t, v_sol)
plt.ylabel('$v(t)$', fontsize=22)
plt.xlabel('$t$', fontsize=22)

plt.plot(t, x_sol)
plt.ylabel('$x(t)$', fontsize=22)
plt.xlabel('$t$', fontsize=22)

plt.show()
```

Corrected code:

```
from scipy import integrate
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math

def dvdt(t, v):
    
    k = 0.3
    Fs = 200000
    m0 = 10000
    lam = 200
    
    return (Fs + k*v**2) / (m0 - lam*t)

v0 = 0

def dxdt(t, x):
    
    k = 0.3
    Fs = 200000
    m0 = 10000
    lam = 200
    
    return math.sqrt(Fs / (dvdt(t, 0)*k))

x0 = 0

t = np.linspace(0, 30, 100)

sol_v = integrate.solve_ivp(dvdt, t_span = (0, max(t)), y0=[v0], t_eval=t)
v_sol = sol_v.y[0]

sol_x = integrate.solve_ivp(dxdt, t_span = (0, max(t)), y0=[x0], t_eval=t)
x_sol = sol_x.y[0]

plt.plot(t, v_sol, label="v(t)")
plt.plot(t, x_sol, label="x(t)")

plt.ylabel('Geschwindigkeit', fontsize=15)
plt.xlabel('Zeit', fontsize=15)

plt.legend(["v(t) - Geschwindigkeit", "x(t) - Höhe"])
plt.title("Verhalten der Rakete")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer and provide the ODE(s) you're trying to solve? In the meantime, you can't divide by the function `dvdt`. You need to evaluate the function first, i.e `math.sqrt(Fs / dvdt(t, x) * k)`.

Comment: I solved my issue by calling dvdt(t, 0) instead of just dvdt -- I completely forgot that it doesn't make sense to call a function without any input and since this models a rocket flight, v0 must be equal to 0 :O)

Comment: The correct ODE function is `lambda t,x: [x[1], dvdt(t,x[1])]`. Anyway, your formula is wrong if `v` is positive, as then the friction term adds acceleration. In general it should be `-k*v*abs(v)`.